# Cannot echo HTML string in PHP using POSTed variable

Tags: php, html

**Context:**

using PHP to echo HTML.

**Issue:**

Echoed HTML does not display unless I've hard-coded $n (i.e. $n = 2;).

**Trouble-shooting:**

-I've confirmed that I'm receiving the POST data via echo,var_dump,print_r.

-I've confirmed that the for loop works by substituting hard-coded numbers for $n.

-I've made sure that the string being received via POST is an integer.

```
   <?php
   $n=intval($_POST["a"]);

    for($count=1;$count<=$n;$count++) 
    {
    echo '<li>foo ' . $count . ':<input type="text" name="bar' . $count . '" value="baz ' .  $count . '"></li>';
    };
    ?>
```

EDIT: The PHP gets POST from AJAX (see below)

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#formid").change(function(){
     $.ajax({
        url     : $(this).attr('action'),
            type    : $(this).attr('method'),
            data    : $(this).serialize(),
            success : function( response ) {
                        alert( response );
                      }
        });
    $("#div1").load("load.php");
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Did you do a `var_dump($n)` to see what you're actually using in the loop? Plus, your `value` portion of the echo is incorrect. you're stuffing the literal text `baz . $count` into your value field, not (say) `baz5`.

Comment: please see under "Trouble-shooting" also, I have edited the echo -- I copy/pasted incorrectly

Comment: if you are posting number 1, you will not enter into loop because 1<=1 is true. maybe that is the issue?

Comment: good thought -- been using numbers > 1 to avoid this issue

Comment: I have a feeling this is a PEBKAC-type error.

Comment: thanks mike! you da best!

Comment: @user3435933 what is the output of `var_dump($_POST["a"])`?

Comment: mike, output is string(1) "2"

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** As per [`your originally posted question`](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/22584902/1)

You are missing a `'` after `value="baz`

```
value="baz .  $count . '"></li>
          ^ // right there
```

Full echo should be:

```
echo '<li>foo ' . $count . ':<input type="text" name="bar' . $count . '" value="baz' .  $count . '"></li>';
```

This has bitten me before, and what I usually do to concatenate long strings is after each period, I hit enter and create a new line.

Remember, PHP is white-space insensitive so feel free to separate lines all you'd like.

Comment: Reasons I hate concatenation :) `"<li>foo $count:<input type='text' name='bar$count' value='baz$count'></li>"`

Comment: Sorry, I copy and pasted incorrectly -- in my original code I had a single-quote.  I have edited my code block to reflect.

Comment: You should try Marc's suggestion above and var_dump($n) before the loop.

Comment: I just ran your updated code in the PHP shell, ran just fine...Sorry, I can't answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear as to what your expected result should be, yet using the (*fixed*) code that follows, produced the following in HTML source:

```
<li>foo 1:<input type="text" name="bar1" value="baz1"></li>
<li>foo 2:<input type="text" name="bar2" value="baz2"></li>
<li>foo 3:<input type="text" name="bar3" value="baz3"></li>
<li>foo 4:<input type="text" name="bar4" value="baz4"></li>
<li>foo 5:<input type="text" name="bar5" value="baz5"></li>
```

PHP (using `5` as a number)

Sidenote: I added  `. "\n"` at the end of the code for clarity.

```
<?php

// $n=intval($_POST["a"]);

   $n=intval(5);

    for($count=1;$count<=$n;$count++) 
    {

echo '<li>foo ' . $count . ':<input type="text" name="bar' . $count . '" value="baz' .  $count . '"></li>' . "\n";

    };
?>
```

---

### Edit

Successful test with form included:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

//   $n=intval(5);

   $n=intval($_POST["a"]);

    for($count=1;$count<=$n;$count++) 
    {
echo '<li>foo ' . $count . ':<input type="text" name="bar' . $count . '" value="baz' .  $count . '"></li>' . "\n";

    };

}

?>

<form method="post" action="">

Number: 
<input type="text" name="a">
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Sidenote:

Just to test both methods - one with and one without (intval), `$n=$_POST["a"];` also worked.

Comment: yeah, I think it has something to do with the POST.  If you notice in the post, I note that hardcoding works but using POST doesn't.

Comment: Let me see what I can do. I'll make up a quick form to test it. @user3435933

Comment: @Fred-ii- You don't need a form. Just do `$_POST["a"] = "5";` or whatever you want to set it to.

Comment: I know Mike, but I added a complete PHP/HTML form for OP to test in my edit. @Mike since it may be coming from a form; most likely ;-)